# Decimal to Binary Program

Tags: c

I am working on an assignment for a C Programming course in regards to converting a decimal to binary using a function that takes in an unsigned char as its input and has a void output. The function will print the binary code of the unsigned char. A hint for the assignment is to create an array of exponents starting with 128 and going down to 1.

I started working on the assignment and ran the debugger, but my program is not working and I am getting a run time error message: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable `userInput` was corrupted.

I would appreciate some suggestions on how I can fix my code and if there is a much simple way to write it in order to make the code easier to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char DecimalToBinary(unsigned char decimalInput);

void main() {

    unsigned char userInput = ' ';
    unsigned char resultOfUserInput = DecimalToBinary(userInput);

    printf("Enter a number less than 256: ");
    scanf_s("%u", &userInput);


    printf("%u in binary: %u", userInput, resultOfUserInput);


    system("pause");
}

unsigned char DecimalToBinary(unsigned char decimalNumber) {

    int arrayOfExponents[128] = {}, i = 1, j;

    while (decimalNumber > 0) {

        arrayOfExponents[i] = decimalNumber % 2;
        i++;
        decimalNumber = decimalNumber / 2;
    }

    for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        printf("%i", arrayOfExponents[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good compliers,properly enabled, will point out issues as in `unsigned char userInput = ' '; ... scanf_s("%u", &userInput);`  Save time and check out your compilers warning settings.

Answer (score 1):

`%u` reads an unsigned int (say 4 bytes) and you are trying to read it into variable `userInput` (1 byte)

Answer (score 0):

Few things 

1) `scanf_s("%u", &userInput);` please change it to `scanf_s("%c", &userInput);`

2) You are calling `DecimalToBinary` before reading user input

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned DecimalToBinary(unsigned char decimalInput);

int main(void) {//void is invalid as a return value.
    unsigned userInput = 256;
    unsigned resultOfUserInput;//DecimalToBinary(userInput);userInput did not input at this point.

    printf("Enter a number less than 256: ");
    if(1 != scanf_s("%u", &userInput)){
        printf("invaid input!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(userInput >= 256){
        printf("More than 256 of the value has been entered.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    resultOfUserInput = DecimalToBinary((unsigned char)userInput);
    printf("%u in binary: %u\n", userInput, resultOfUserInput);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

unsigned DecimalToBinary(unsigned char decimalNumber) {
    unsigned bin = 0, exp = 1;//assert(sizeof(unsigned) >= 4);

    while (decimalNumber > 0) {
        bin += (decimalNumber & 1) * exp;
        decimalNumber >>= 1;
        exp *= 10;
    }

    return bin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to convert numbers from base 10 to any other base using recursion. I have shared one example with you. You can have any other number as your base.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void baseconvert(int number,int base) 
{
    if(number > 0) 
    {
        int digit = (number % base);
        baseconvert(number / base, base);
        printf("%d",digit);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() 
{
    baseconvert(1023,2);
    return 0;
}
```